# How to show a module on every page?

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.4, module, module-display

I have the latest version of joomla 3, I want to display JEvents calendar and the default hit counter on every page of the site, I selected all pages but they seem to be displayed on only 1 page.

Comment: Is the module position available in the other pages, than that one?

Comment: @FFrewin no sir, only one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you assigned the module to all pages yet it still displays only on one page, then this might be caused by one of the following:

- You have not cleared your Joomla cache.
- The module is set to display under specific conditions that are only present on that particular page.
- There is a condition at the template level to only display that module position on a specific page.